# add_header for certain request_uri

Tags: nginx

The app handles all the routing. So this basic configuration block works:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

The issue is that I want to add a custom header whenever a visitor requests a certain URI. For example, `/content`. Well, that must be easy as:

```
location ~ ^/content {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   add_header X-CUSTOM-HEADER value;
}
```

But that doesn't work. Nginx is not creating that header. Then, I tried to remove the `try_files` directive from the **content** block but that doesn't work obviously as there's no "real" `/content` folder in the root directory. Thus, nginx will throw **404 not found** error.

I also tried to move that block inside the root location block. Not working either.

---

In Apache, this can be done easily using this:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ pattern">
    Header set HEADER value;
</If>
```

Comment: Why do you use a regex in your `location`? It doesn't appear to be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the header using a mapped variable. If the variable is set to an empty string, the header will be silently discarded.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $myheader {
    ~^/content   a_value;
}
server {
    ...
    add_header X-CUSTOM-HEADER $myheader;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think about it. This works!!! I've spent hours finding out how to do this! Thanks!