# Config for different headers for different paths but always end up serving the same file

Tags: nginx

I would like to serve different headers for different locations but fallback to always serving a specific file (if no matching file can be found).

I've also got some global headers that needed to be added to all the requests, though with the caveat that I don't want them added if they've already been added at the `location` level.

I've got this `.template.conf` so far:

```
server {   
   listen   ${PORT};
   # Don't include any local server address info in redirects
   absolute_redirect off;

   index    index.html;

   root ${HTML_SRC};

   include  ${INCLUDE_DIR}/*.conf;
    
   # Serve any matching requested file (CSS, etc.) fallbacking to /index.html
   location / {
      # First try a matching existing file, then just show index.html
      try_files     $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
}
```

The `include` (in `INCLUDE_DIR/headers.conf`) is defined as:

```
# Global headers
add_header  X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"  always;
add_header  Cache-Control   "no-store, must-revalidate" always;
add_header  Report-To   "<global-config>" always;
add_header  Content-Security-Policy "<global-config>" always;

# Location specific paths

# Specific known existing file in /$HTML_SRC/.well-known
location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association$ {
    default_type    application/json;
    # Redirect everything to fallback / location to serve the file
    rewrite .* / last;
}

# Assets
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ttf)$ {
    # Redeclare global headers (not inherited)
    add_header  X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"  always;
    add_header  Report-To   "<global-config>" always;
    add_header  Content-Security-Policy "<global-config>" always;
    # Cache assets for a bit longer
    add_header  Cache-Control   "max-age=31557600";
    # Redirect everything to fallback / location to serve any files file
    rewrite .* / last;
}

location = /login {
    # Redeclare global headers (not inherited)
    add_header  X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"  always;
    add_header  Cache-Control   "no-store, must-revalidate" always;
    # Path specific CSP headers
    add_header  Report-To   "<specific-config>" always;
    add_header  Content-Security-Policy "<specific-config>" always;
    # Redirect everything to /
    rewrite .* / last;
}

# All locations with this prefix have these headers
location /some-other-path {
    # Redeclare global headers (not inherited)
    add_header  X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"  always;
    add_header  Cache-Control   "no-store, must-revalidate" always;
    # Path specific CSP headers
    add_header  Report-To   "<other-specific-config>" always;
    add_header  Content-Security-Policy "<other-specific-config>" always;
    # Redirect everything to /
    rewrite .* / last;
}
```

I realise that any `location`s with `add_header` means any top level (in this case in the `server` in the template) `add_header`s [are not inherited](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header).

The problem with the above is that it just doesn't quite work! The `location` specific headers aren't always used. I think it's the `rewrite` that's the issue, but I've also tried `try_files` (matching the template one) without success. I've also tried having nothing except the extra headers in the `location` block without no luck. I also think what I'm doing isn't the best approach too...

Note that I've simplified the headers added, the CSP headers are included for example, there are other global headers and other location specific ones. I've also got other paths that need different headers but I think the stuff I've got above can be fixed with a generic solution I can apply to those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rewrite...last` will cause Nginx to [search for a new location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) to process the request. Only the final `location` gets to set response headers.

You could process the entire request within the same `location` block that sets the response headers with `rewrite...break` or more simply [using `try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) as follows:

```
try_files /index.html =404;
```

*Notice that the `/index.html` term is **not** last parameter. If it was the last parameter, it would cause Nginx to search for a new location to process the request.*

---

Alternatively, keep all of your `add_header` statements together, and use a `map` to set specific values. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1074229/add-header-for-certain-request-uri/1074231#1074231).

Comment: "Only the final location gets to set response headers." -- ahh this makes things a lot clearer knowing this now, thanks!

Comment: `try_files /index.html =404;` but will this still try getting known existing files? does `try_files` implicitly try for existence of a matching file first or is `try_files $uri /index.html =404` needed for that?

Comment: "If it was the last parameter, it would cause Nginx to search for a new location to process the request." Also this tiny important gem solves a lot of things too!

Comment: `try_files /index.html =404;` is intended to replace your `rewrite .* / last;` where **everything** is redirected to `index.html`. To get existing files and/or directories, you will need to add a `$uri` and/or `$uri/` file term to the `try_files` statement.